# Cannot resolve symbol 'permission' Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-permissions

This is the line of code I'm having issues with

```
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

It's inside my `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

There is no option to import anything

[image: img]

Here is a list of my imports

[image: img2]

Comment: You appear to have an `import` statement for a `Manifest` class. What exactly is that `import` statement?

Comment: Hmm, here is a list of all my imports http://i.imgur.com/Jcg0eTH.png

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are importing the wrong Manifest class...

```
// import java.util.jar.Manifest; // wrong

import android.Manifest; // correct
```

or use `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 4):

You should import

**android.Manifest** and not  **java.util.jar.Manifest**